# Postfix: Set connection rate limit exceeded per host

Tags: postfix

Is it possible to define the `smtpd_client_connection_count_limit` per domain in Postfix? I have a default setting of `smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 10`, but I want to allow a higher limit for domains like mx.example.com.

Comment: It is not until the SMTP conversation is well underway that the domain is identified (i.e. after connection is established) so it possibly not a very good way to manage capacity/traffic. Run a separate instance of postfix at a different IP optionally with the original as it's smart relay?

Comment: I meant not the recipients domain, but smtp host. Like allow higher connections rate if mail is coming from mx.example.com. or whitelist by IP?

Comment: You mean outgoing connections? Then look at default_destination_concurrency_limit. To specify different behaviour for a specific domain on a single server, I think you'd need to implement a separate transport for the destination the use https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_destination_concurrency_limit

Comment: No, I meant incoming. Lets say I have a secondary mx server that forwards certain mail to the primary. Since it is trusted server, I can accept mail at much higher rate than from the "outside".

Comment: Then back to first comment.

Comment: The default for this is `50` and the [documentation](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_connection_count_limit) explains it: `WARNING: The purpose of this feature is to limit abuse. It must not be used to regulate legitimate mail traffic.`. It looks like you are trying to do that.

Comment: please update the question to share what you are working on. What is the business related question in here? and what is the business related problem?

Answer (score 1):

postfix has a special parameter https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html
smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions (default: $mynetworks)
Clients that are excluded from smtpd_client_*_count/rate_limit restrictions. See the mynetworks parameter description for the parameter value syntax.

So I did it in such a way
main.cf
**smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions = $mynetworks hash:/etc/postfix/event-limit-exceptions**

in file /etc/postfix/event-limit-exceptions
**mx.example.com  TRUE**

**postmap /etc/postfix/event-limit-exceptions**